# Why do I get the error , takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given I literally followed everything my teacher did

Tags: python

I am new to OOP and having trouble figuring out what I am doing wrong

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

class pup(Dog):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(pup, self)
sammy = pup('sammy')

print(sammy.name)
```

Comment: If that's what your teacher did, your teacher made a mistake. There's no need to define `pup.__init__` at all, but if you do, it should call `super().__init__(name)`.

Answer (score 2):

So, the idea by having OOP inheritance is that you have a sub-class (`Puppy`) with inherits its "behaviour" from a super-class (`Dog`) i.e all the properties a dog has the puppy also does, as default.

Thus you almost always want to initialize the sub-class in the same way as the super-class is initialized, since it's there a lot of instances are set.

With your example, lets give the `Dog` an attribute called `name` and a method called `bark`

```py
class Dog:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def bark(self):
        print("woof")
```

we can then create an instance of that which works fine

```py
dog = Dog("sammy")
print(dog.name) # "sammy"
dog.bark() # "woof"
```

Now, we want to create a sub-class called `Pub` which should have the same method (`bark`) and attribute (`name`) as `Dog`. Lets just initialize it by doing nothing

```py
class Pup(Dog):
    def __init__(self,name):
        pass

pup = Pup("sammy")
pup.bark() # "woof"
pup.name # AttributeError: 'pup' object has no attribute 'name'
```

as you can see, it does not have a name, because we have overwritten the `__init__` function from the parent (`Dog`) that should've set that attribute. Because of that, we need to call the parents `__init__` function inside our function

```py
class Pup(Dog):
    def __init__(self,name):
        super().__init__(name) #call the Dogs __init__ function

pup = Pup('sammy')
pup.bark() # "woof"
print(pup.name) # "sammy"
```

This is of course a toy-example and we could simply just set the name attribute just by copying the lines from `Dog`s `__init__` method into `Pup`s `__init__` method, but the idea with inheritance is to avoid all this code copy-paste.

When you create this sub-class `Pup` with a super-class `Dog` you (losely)  say; "create a class called `Pup` by copying all the code from Dog into Pup"

Comment: If you don't define `Pup.__init__` at all, then `Dog.__init__` is inherited and it will be called with `name` as its argument. That's preferable to explicitly defining an unnecessary wrapper.

Comment: Good point - this was just for illustration purporse of why the `super().__init__` was there etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

class pup(Dog):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Dog.__init__(self, name)
sammy = pup('sammy')

print(sammy.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to pass the `self` to `super().__init__()` on line 7.

Also, I think you should implement it this way:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

class pup(Dog):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
sammy = pup('sammy')

print(sammy.name)
```

Comment: There's no point in defining `pup.__init__` if all it does is call `super().__init__` with the exact same arguments.